# How to calculate time complexity of a modified quick sort mixed with insertion sort?

Tags: c, sorting, time-complexity

I know how to calculate complexity for Quick Sort and Insertion Sort alone, but when I mix the two...

Here is the code:

```
#define THRESHOLD 50

// regular insertion sort
void isort(int *array, size_t n) {
  int key, i, j;
  for(j = 1; j < n; j++){
    key = array[j];
    i = j - 1;
    while (array[i] > key && i>=0) {
      array[i + 1] = array[i];
      i--;
    }
    array[i + 1] = key;
  }
}

// modified quick sort
static void sort(int *array, int start, int end) {
  if (end - start > THRESHOLD) {
    int pivot = array[start];
    int l = start + 1;
    int r = end;
    while(l < r) {
       if (array[l] < pivot) {
          l += 1;
       } else if ( array[r] >= pivot )  {
          r -= 1;
       } else {
          swap(&array[l], &array[r]);
       }
    }
    if (array[l] < pivot) {
      swap(&array[start], &array[l]);
      l -= 1;
    } else {
      l -= 1;
      swap(&array[start], &array[l]);
    }

    sort(array, start, l);
    sort(array, r, end);
  } else {
    isort(array, end - start + 1);
  }
}
```

To summarize: this is a recursive Quick Sort, except that when the incoming vector is below the threshold, it uses the Insertion Sort.

How do I calculate the time complexity for best, average and worst cases?

Comment: what is the value of THRESHOLD

Comment: I've updated the code!

Comment: Best case complexity is utterly pointless.

Comment: Yoursort is still O(n^2) in the worst case.

Answer (score 2):

The part that is confusing is that when the partition gets of size 50 or less we do an insertion sort. The particular value (50) is not that important so I will switch it to 64 for a bit easier calculations. When doing the recursive formula for the average case of qsort we assume that sorting a partition of size 64 takes log(64) * 64 operations, which apparently is a constant. Note that 64 is a constant and sorting 64 elements with insert will take in the order of O(64 * 64) even in the worst case. That is still a constant. So we will only change the constant of the asymptotic behavior complexity of qsort, but we will not change the function itself.

That being said my point is that performing another algorithm below a fixed threshold may change the constant factor of your algorithm but it will not change its complexity. It will remain the same for all cases you've mentioned.